# jquery ajax load certain div

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

my question is very simple how can I retrieve certain div with jquery ajax comand

```
$.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
      success: function(){
           $(this).addClass("done");
      }
  });
```

like with load

```
$('#targetDiv').load('http://localhost/test.html #sourceDiv');
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't simply use `load()`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the div is part of the AJAX response:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        var div = $('#sourceDiv', $(html)).addClass('done');
        $('#targetDiv').html(div);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but there is something wrong this does not run at all,when loading finish my target div is empty

Comment: @Yovo, does the returned HTML contains a div with `id="sourceDiv"`? Try looking with FireBug the server response and log the div variable in the success callback.

Comment: actually firebug shows it is loaded. I try to load whole file and everything works fine  but when I select particular DIV the browser is hiding it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a slightly different take on it.  Also your target div maybe hidden by default so I've added in a Fade In affect to show it.  If your html is going to change then you might want to add in a cache: false.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "html.htm",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function (res) {
       $("#targetDiv").html($(res).find("#sourceDiv")
                                  .addClass('done'))
                     .fadeIn('slow');
  }
});
```

If you're interested you can take a look at how jQuery does the load method here [jQuery Source Viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.5.0&fn=load)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that I use on my site for the navigation.

```
<ul id="nav">        
    <li><a name="portfolio" href="portfolio.php" class="ajax_nav">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a name="biography" href="biography.php" class="ajax_nav">BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
</ul>
```

For the javascript you can try this.

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var hash2 = window.location.hash.substr(1);

// Menu items to lower main content
var href = $('.ajax_nav').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #ajax_content';
        $('#ajax_content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

// For inner overlay of featured content. 
var href2 = $('.feat_item_link').each(function(){
    var href2 = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash2==href2.substr(0,href.length-4)){
        var toLoadFeatured = hash2+'.html #ajax_featured_content';
        $('#ajax_featured_content').load(toLoadFeatured);
    }                                           
});

// For Bottom Navigation
$('#nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #ajax_content';
    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');

    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href'));
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').delay(1000).load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').delay(1000).fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;
});
```

The id of #load simply uses an animated gif in the CSS.

Place the javascript in the $(document).ready() and you should be all set.